# LightningChartJS synchronizeAxisIntervals causes X-axis to "overflow"

Tags: lightningchart

The X-axis of my first chart "overflows" after calling synchronizeAxisIntervals.

```
synchronizeAxisIntervals(...charts.map((chart) => chart.getDefaultAxisX()));
chartL.getDefaultAxisX().fit(true);
```

Any ideas?

[image]